# Problem with copying one array to another using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I'm student of an online university, there was a lecture about copying one populated array to another empty array, i didn't quite get it and even by given code line by i was not able to get required results. (Note in video lecture they didn't "cout" to check if there code worked or not).

```
ptrA = str1;
ptrB = str2;

while(*ptrA != '\0'){
cout << *ptrA;    // it works fine shows output
ptrA++;
}

while(*ptrA != '\0'){
*ptrB++ = *ptrA++;
}
*ptrB = '\0';

while(*ptrB != '\0'){
cout << *ptrB;     // this doesn't show any thing and crashes
ptrB++;
}
```

First cout works just fine shows output "Playing with pointers" but after copying or duplicating str1 to str2 last output doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use a debugger to watch the value of `ptrB` after the loop where it gets filled. Tip: It points somewhere not at the beginning of the array.

Comment: after the first loop `ptrA` does already point to the end of the string, the second loop will run exactly zero times

Comment: It was so obvious reset the pointer location as at this line instructor said ptrB is at last address so when we put this line *ptrB = '\0'; it will be the last element in array thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each `ptrB++`, you loose the pointer to where `ptrB` originally started. So you can't use `ptrB` as is in a second loop without reseting it to the beginning of the respective string. The same applies to `ptrA`:

```
ptrA = str1;
while(*ptrA != '\0'){
  *ptrB++ = *ptrA++;
}
*ptrB = '\0';

ptrB = str2;
while(*ptrB != '\0'){
  cout << *ptrB;
  ptrB++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing pointers and then somehow expect them to point again to the beginning of the string. You probably want to reset the pointers to the beginning again

```
auto beginA = ptrA;
auto beginB = ptrB;

while(*ptrA != '\0'){
    cout << *ptrA;    // it works fine shows output
    ptrA++;
}

ptrA = beginA;  // reset to beginning, otherwise ptrA == '\0'

while(*ptrA != '\0'){
    *ptrB++ = *ptrA++;
}
*ptrB = '\0';

ptrB = beginA;

while(*ptrB != '\0'){
    cout << *ptrB;     // this doesn't show any thing and crashes
    ptrB++;
}
```

Note that in your code you have

```
*ptrB = '\0';
while(*ptrB != '\0'){
```

ie the while loop was not printing anything because it was never executed. Same for the loop that copies the data: After the first loop `ptrA == '\0'`.